# CORS issue with Angular 2 in Chrome normal mode

Tags: google-chrome, angular, cors

I am running an Angular 2 application generated using `angular-cli`. I am using the code below to make a HTTP GET request to a server which allows cross origin requests.

```
getItems(): Promise<Items[]> {      
    return this.http.get(this.url).toPromise().then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        response.json() as Item[];
    }).catch(this.handleError);
}
```

The above function gets called when a certain page loads to retrieve a list of items. When I test the application in *Chrome Incognito* mode the data is fetched and logs the received response. But when I try it out in normal mode I get the error below.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://10.20.10.16/api/items. Request header field x-xsrf-token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

I am using `ng serve` to run the Angular 2 application.

I tried the same HTTP GET request using the jQuery code below and that works in Chrome normal mode.

```
$(document).ready(function(){                   
    $.ajax('http://10.20.10.16/api/items').done(function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    }).fail(function() {
        console.log('Error');
    }).always(function() {
        console.log('Completed');
    });
});
```

I thought it was a cache issue so I cleared the cache for the last two days which is when I started working on this application.

I also tried the Angular 2 application in Internet Explorer and it works fine without any CORS errors.

It seems to be a caching issue but I do not want to clear my entire cache. How can I fix this?

Comment: What you could do is kill al the chrome processes. Perform a hard refresh by doing ctrl + F5. Go in to chrome settings and remove everything related to localhost. Go to devtools of chrome => network tab => disable cache.

Comment: If I disable cache wont that apply to the browser globally? I still want to have cache on cause I need to for the applications I use. Rather killing the Chrome process, I guess I could kill the task I guess. But I found a solution, I restarted the browser and restored history. And now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem by restarting the browser and restoring its history. I also removed everything related localhost beforehand.

I guess it could have worked by clearing the browser history but I didn't want to do that.